# How to find the dropped area class or id telerick asp.net mvc drag and drop

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-mvc

How to find the dropped area class or id telerick asp.net mvc  treeview drag and drop when there are many drop areas.

I am using

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/treeview/draganddrop

look at this link  http://jsfiddle.net/hPTB5/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [OnNodeDrop](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-treeview-client-api-and-events.html#OnNodeDrop) event and the e.dropTarget field exposed by the argument object of the event.

Then you can simply get the class like this:

```
function onYourTreeViewNodeDrop(e){
    var classOfTheDropTarget = $(e.dropTarget).attr('class');
}
```